objdump of Hello world file in c
I wanted to check the disassembled code of a hello world file in c to understand the assembly instructions it was using to run the code.
I tried compiling the Hello.c file to the object code using gcc Hello.c -c Hello.o and used objdump to disassemble the file into a Hello.s file. The command was objdump -D -Mamd64 ./Hello.o >> a.s. But when I searched for the "Hello, World" string or other things like printf, I did not find them in the disassembled file.
Here is the C file:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}

and the disassembled file:

./Hello.o:     file format pe-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>
   e:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  15:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1a <_main+0x1a>
  1a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  1f:   c9                      leave  
  20:   c3                      ret    
  21:   90                      nop
  22:   90                      nop
  23:   90                      nop

Disassembly of section .rdata:

00000000 <.rdata>:
   0:   48                      dec    %eax
   1:   65 6c                   gs insb (%dx),%es:(%edi)
   3:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%edi)
   4:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
   5:   2c 20                   sub    $0x20,%al
   7:   57                      push   %edi
   8:   6f                      outsl  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
   9:   72 6c                   jb     77 <.rdata+0x77>
   b:   64 21 00                and    %eax,%fs:(%eax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .rdata$zzz:

00000000 <.rdata$zzz>:
   0:   47                      inc    %edi
   1:   43                      inc    %ebx
   2:   43                      inc    %ebx
   3:   3a 20                   cmp    (%eax),%ah
   5:   28 4d 69                sub    %cl,0x69(%ebp)
   8:   6e                      outsb  %ds:(%esi),(%dx)
   9:   47                      inc    %edi
   a:   57                      push   %edi
   b:   2e 6f                   outsl  %cs:(%esi),(%dx)
   d:   72 67                   jb     76 <.rdata$zzz+0x76>
   f:   20 47 43                and    %al,0x43(%edi)
  12:   43                      inc    %ebx
  13:   2d 36 2e 33 2e          sub    $0x2e332e36,%eax
  18:   30 2d 31 29 20 36       xor    %ch,0x36202931
  1e:   2e 33 2e                xor    %cs:(%esi),%ebp
  21:   30 00                   xor    %al,(%eax)
    ...

Disassembly of section .eh_frame:

00000000 <.eh_frame>:
   0:   14 00                   adc    $0x0,%al
   2:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   4:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   6:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   8:   01 7a 52                add    %edi,0x52(%edx)
   b:   00 01                   add    %al,(%ecx)
   d:   7c 08                   jl     17 <.eh_frame+0x17>
   f:   01 1b                   add    %ebx,(%ebx)
  11:   0c 04                   or     $0x4,%al
  13:   04 88                   add    $0x88,%al
  15:   01 00                   add    %eax,(%eax)
  17:   00 1c 00                add    %bl,(%eax,%eax,1)
  1a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  1c:   1c 00                   sbb    $0x0,%al
  1e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  20:   04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
  22:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  24:   21 00                   and    %eax,(%eax)
  26:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
  28:   00 41 0e                add    %al,0xe(%ecx)
  2b:   08 85 02 42 0d 05       or     %al,0x50d4202(%ebp)
  31:   5d                      pop    %ebp
  32:   c5 0c 04                lds    (%esp,%eax,1),%ecx
  35:   04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
    ...



The "48 65 6c 6c..." in rdata is the hello world string.

All the call instructions have a zero argument and you are looking at the object file, so this is some relocatable format and the actual address is going to be inserted by the linker later. pe-i386 so some 32bit windows? mingw? I don't have that on hand so I can't tell you the incantations to see something less silly.

https://godbolt.org/z/svx3oq9KM <- what you probably wanted to see

-D is not really useful here — there's no point in disassembling data, and it is probably why you missed that the data does indeed contain that string.

-dr on the other hand, would be useful. That would show the relocation entries.
